# How can I output a table containing the count of all items that match this condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, cs50

I'm working in CS50 pset7 SQLite queries, and I'm stuck in this problem:
`write a SQL query to determine the number of movies with an IMDb rating of 10.0. Your query should output a table with a single column and a single row (plus optional header) containing the number of movies with a 10.0 rating.`
So basically what I have to do is go into a table called 'ratings',[image: table structure]

which has the strucutre of the image above, and get the number of how many items in the column rating has a value of `10.0`.

I have tried `count(SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE rating=10.0` but I believe count doesn't work like that...

Hopefully you can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below -

```
   select count(*)
     FROM ratings WHERE rating=10.0
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I will mark the answer accepted in 2 min (it will only allow me then). Can you mark my answer useful? I believe this is an important question because CS50 doesn't tech this. Thanks!

Comment: COUNT is introduced at [21:40 of the lecture](https://youtu.be/u5pDdEKnbKA?t=1300). It is also presented in the [SQL section of the Notes](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/notes/7/#sql)

Answer (score 0):

For returning number of rows of table we use count(*) function of SQL.
`Select count(*)  from ratings where rating where rating = 10.0 ;`